# Set Cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I get the basic concept of set cardinality. For example if you have $A = \{3, 4, 5, 6\}$, the set cardinality would be $4$.

What I don't grasp is problems like: $A = \{a, a \{b, a \{a \}\}\}$ or $A = \{a\}$

Comment: Are there a few commas missing in the first example? Shouldn't it be $A=\{a,a,\{b,a,\{a\}\}\}$?

Comment: You count the things that are inside the set, not the things inside of the things inside of the set. $\{a,b,\{c,d\}\}$ has cardinality of 3, not 4 (its elements are $a$, $b$, and $\{c,d\}$).

Comment: ... assuming $a \neq b$ and $a \neq \{c,d\}$ and $b \neq \{c, d\}$.

Answer (score 6):

You just count how many *separate* things there are in the set. Whether these *things* are subsets, symbols, functions or whatever doesn't matter. Each *thing* counts as one. Thus,

- $|\{a\}| = 1$
- $|\{a,a\}| = 1$ since both $a$s are presumably the same *thing*
- $|\{1,\{2,3,4,5\}\}| = 2$ since the set contains $1$ and $\{2,3,4,5\}$ with are two distinct *things*
- $|\{a,\{a\},\{\{a\}\}|=3$ since $a$, $\{a\}$, $\{\{a\}\}$ are three distinct *things*. The latter two are distinct because one is a set with contains $a$, and the second is a set which contains a set which contains $a$.

To test whether two sets are equal, you have to check whether they contain *exactly* the same *things*. If every *thing* contains in $A$ is also contained in $B$, and the other way round, then (and only then) are $A$ and $B$ equal.

Comment: ... and by the axiom of regularity, $a \neq \{a\}$, and $a \neq \{\{a\}\}$.